# how to delete foreign key rows sql server?

Tags: sql-server

I have table A and Table B,
Table A references with foreign key on B primary key,
when I delete row from A I want to delete also rows in B that A is referencing with foreign key, How can I do it? Cascade delete doesn't work because I don't know which B rows I want to delete i only know A table rows

Comment: What happens if there are multiple rows in A that ref the primary key in B - what should happen to the row in B in that case?

Comment: Cascade delete would only work in any case if you were deleting from table B first, as it would then cascade down the foreign keys.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have cascading deletes enabled, so that A-rows will automatically be deleted when B-rows are deleted?

In that case, you can simply do something like this:

```
DELETE B FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.ForeignKey = B.PrimaryKey
WHERE <some condition on A or B or both>
```

Cascading deletes will take care of deleting all records from A that are referring to the records in B, that are about to be deleted.

If you do not have cascading deletes, you will need to change the above to a SELECT statement where you output the primary keys from B into a temporary table. Then use this temporary table to delete all records from A, that refer to these B primary keys. Then finally delete the records from B using the temporary table.